# "while loop" returns unexpected "undefined"

Tags: javascript, while-loop, undefined

Sorry if it is a really simple question but I really cannot figure it out. I have to simply write on the screen the numbers from 1 to 8, without using a `for` loop. I tried using a `while` loop, like this:

```
var y=1;
function scrie(y){
  while (y<=8){
    document.write(y + " ");
    y++;
  }
}
```

And it does show the numbers, but in the end, there is an `undefined`, like here:

```
     1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 undefined
```

What could be the problem?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where you called the function? And why there is argument `y` in the function.

Comment: How are you calling the `scrie` function ?

Comment: Perhaps, you're calling it like this: `document.write(scrie(y))`? Then this `undefined` is an [undefined] result of function.

Comment: The only way I've been able to recreate what you're talking about is with what @Styx suggests.

Comment: @Styx That's definitely the reason. He would get the same result if he replaced `document.write` with `console.log` and then called that function in the browser's console

Comment: @Styx rewrite the comment as an answer with a recommended solution or two, and it'll get my upvote.

Comment: @CalIrvine I'd like to close the question as "can't be reproduced as it was a typo/mistake" :)

Comment: That's why I asked him how he called the function

Comment: @Fraction 99.9% that outer `document.write` is the culprit :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call `scrie` function using `document.write()` it will print `undefined` at the end since `scrie` function doesn't return anything.

To solve that issue just remove outer `document.write()` call, like this:

```js
var y=1;
function scrie(y){
  while (y<=8){
    document.write(y + " ");
    y++;
  }
}

scrie(y);
```

Comment: oohh, that was it! thank you so much! also, should i use `return` here? or is it redundant?

Comment: No, in your case you don't need `return`, just call your function without `document.write`